# Error CS0234 and CS0246 on new project using VS2019 WebApi Template

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

After create a new project using the default template for MVC Web API and build, we get numerous errors CS0234  and  CS0246 such as :

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Web'.

AND

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not
>   be found

Updating the NutGet Packages  or Reinstalling the ASP.NET package do not help.
Opening an existing project of the same type does not throw any errors just new projects.
Thanks for your help